# javascript call a privileged method

Tags: javascript

If I call the killSwitch() outside the onkeypress, I'll cause an error.
But inside the onkeypress function, I worked just fine.
Why?

```
// this works fine
var ClassA = function()  
{  
    var doc = document;
// killSwitch();

    doc.onkeypress = function(e){ killSwitch(); }  
    this.killSwitch = function(){ alert('hello world'); }  
}

var myClass = new ClassA();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't call `killSwitch` because you defined the method as a property of the object instance (`this.killSwitch`).

You can't use `this` inside the `keypress` event, because it will refer to the `document`, you have to store the `this` value:

```
var ClassA = function() {  
    var doc = document, 
              instance = this; // store reference to `this`

    doc.onkeypress = function(e){ instance.killSwitch(); }; 
    this.killSwitch = function(){ alert('hello world'); };
}

var myClass = new ClassA();
```

Comment: Rats, you beat me to it by 30 seconds! +1, nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var ClassA = function()  
{  
    var doc = document;
    var killSwitch = function(){ alert('hello world'); };
    killSwitch();

    doc.onkeypress = function(e){ killSwitch(); }  
    this.killSwitch = killSwitch  
}

var myClass = new ClassA();
```

This way you define the `killSwitch` function inside the `ClassA` function, creating a closure, and it is available both within and outside the class.